# How to solve for a problem using a primitive function in toc

Tags: turing-machines

I have been searching on the internet how to multiply a function but I cannot find any. I have only found solution in adding but not in multiplication.

$add(2,3) = s(s(s(add(2,0)))) $

$add(2,3) = s(s(s(I(2))) $

$add(2,3) = s(s(s(2)) $

$add(2,3) = s(s(3)) $

$add(2,3) = s(4) $

$add(2,3) = 5 $

For example, Using the *multiply primitive function*, how to compute $multiply (5, 3)$.

Does anybody know?

Comment: I can't show you the full solution, only a hint. You must also show what you've tried if you really wanna get some help, and not some solution.

Comment: This is a problem dump showing no effort. Try harder.

Comment: And what is "toc"?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You probably have: 
$$add(0, n) = n$$
$$add(m+1, n) = S(add(m,n))$$

Now you know the base case for addition is adding zero. What's the base case for multiplication? Multiplying by zero.

$$mul(0,n) = 0 $$

I will not do the last part,because you must do your own homework,  look at your example and the addition definition, the $mul$ function must work like this:

$$mul(3,5) \longrightarrow 5 + 5 + 5 + 0 $$